# Rspec stub_const race condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm writing rspec tests like so

```
describe Module do
  describe "method" do
    context "first_context" do
      before do
        stub_const("Module::CONST", "stub0")
      end
      # logic
    end

    context "second_context" do
      before do
        stub_const("Module::CONST", "stub0 stub1")
      end
      # logic
    end
  end
end
```

and about 75% of the time the tests pass as the stub_const logic is working, but 25% of the time a race condition fails and the stub_const from the first test flows in to the const for the second test, so the second test's `Module::CONST` value is `"stub0"`. Why is this happening?

Comment: How do you know it's a race condition? Are you running the tests in parallel? There's no enough information in your question. I reproduced your test, run it 100 times and no single fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this sort of thing happen on JRuby. You can try adding explicit locking around any code that stubs globals, or running each of the examples under a lock:

```
$lock = Mutex.new

around do |example|
  $lock.synchronize do
    example.run
  end
end
```

Ensure this is before your `before` hooks.